# How do I pass/open an html page to page viewer web part from list

Tags: page-viewer-web-part, angularjs

I have 2 web parts on a page.

1. WebPart1 is a script viewer displaying a list of links. (like a nav).
2. WebPart2 is up in the air. I want to click the link

> /site/SitePages/thefile.aspx)

in WebPart1 and have WebPart2 auto-fill with the contents.

Using Angular directives also.

```
<b>Nav Html</b>   
<div ng-bind="item.title" ng-click=""></div>
```